# hclust, dist in R explained methods for clustering words

Tags: r, nlp, tm, dendrogram, hclust

I'm working with some tweet data using the twitter API and OAUTH. I am making a cluster dendrogram to cluster words used in 500 tweets. I am not exactly sure how the hclust function is clustering the words. i.e by what rules I need some logic explaining

here is the code

```
 tweetTDM.reduced<-removeSparseTerms(tweetTDM, 0.992)

 d <- dist(tweetTDM.reduced, method="euclidian")
 fit <- hclust(d, method="ward.D")
 plot(fit)
```

[image: RStudio Image]

I included an image of exactly what I'm looking at in R.

Comment: Hierarchical clustering is described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) and in the [SO Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/8084/hierarchical-clustering#t=201701181958562516813).   You used Ward's method as distance.  That is also described in [Wikipedia on Ward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%27s_method)

Comment: For using Ward's method you should set `method="ward.D2"`, since `ward.D` is not a correct implementation of it (unless you square the euclidiean distances that you use)

Comment: @YangLi -- ah, thanks for pointing that out. I need some help understanding exactly what im doing the terms in the tweets. this is what I did I created the term doc matrix                                            tweetTDM<-TermDocumentMatrix(tweetCorpus) then I weighted it tf-idf  tweetTDM2 <-weightTfIdf(tweetTDM, normalize = TRUE) then I removed sparse terms                                                               tweetTDM2.reduced <- removeSparseTerms(tweetTDM2, .992) and finally d <- dist(tweetTDM2.reduced, method="euclidian")     this code is what I dont understand. What does it do